# How can I plot my data from a map in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot

**Context:**

Currently, I have a map of my data where each key will have a value that is incremented, or if the key does not - it will create it - this works fine.

**Problem:**

However, when trying to plot via
`plot(keys(map),values(map));`
this results in "Error using plot, not enough input arguments"

**Code Example:**

```
map = containers.Map({1},{0});

for i=1:10
    keyExists = isKey(map,i);

       
    if (keyExists == 0)
       map(i) = 0; 
    end
       
    map(i) = map(i) + 1;

 end

plot(keys(map),values(map));
```

**Output Example:**

```
>> keys(map)

ans =

  1×10 cell array

    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}    {[4]}    {[5]}    {[6]}    {[7]}    {[8]}    {[9]}    {[10]}
```

I don't quite understand where the problem lies.

Comment: what does `keys(map)` output ? Please create a reproducible example, add the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It produces a 1x20 cell array, the output appearing as {[1]} {[2]} {[...]} - the same with values(map). I will add example code.

Comment: Not sure, about the exact context but casting the outputs as matrices using the `cell2mat()`  function allows plotting: `plot(cell2mat(keys(map)),cell2mat(values(map)));`

Comment: @Michaeltr7 That worked perfectly! Thank you. If you want to put it in a question format I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plotting Cell Arrays by Casting

Plotting outputs typically works best when the data is in the format of arrays. Here casting the arrays using the `cell2mat()` function will convert the `cell` (cell) arrays to `mat` (matrices) which can be plotted with ease.

```
plot(cell2mat(keys(map)),cell2mat(values(map)));
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**